# C# formatting string with several numbers after the dot

Tags: c#, string

I'm recovering the value of a website, however I'm having difficulty formatting the string ...

```
My Value: $314.623230
Expected result: 314.62
```

How i can archive this result?

I have tried to convert the string to decimal and use ToSting() with arguments (N0, N1, 0:0##), but it does not return the expected result ...

Comment: Please show the actual formatting code so we can help correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
decimal d = decimal.Parse("$314.623230", NumberStyles.Currency, usCulture);
string expectedResult = d.ToString("0.##", usCulture); // 314.62
```

Comment: Really thanks, works like a charm :)